# How to pass variable through in modulated files?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have a `askopenfilename()` function inside my main python file which gets a file directory from the user when a button is pressed. My main file is called `payroll.py`.

I have another file called `dataframes.py` which has a function that imports excel files using the `read_excel()` function and then manipulates the data.

This code is in payroll.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import dataframes


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("SportClips Automation 0.0.1")
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        names = ['Instructions', 'Payroll']
        self.nb = self.create_notebook(names)
        self.menu = self.create_menus()

        tab = self.nb.tabs['Instructions']
        tk.Label(tab, text='-Select the "Payroll" tab to run Stylist 
Compensation Worksheets').pack()

        image = tk.PhotoImage(file="1.png")
        tk.Label(tab, image=image).pack()

        self.mainloop()

    def create_notebook(self, names):
        nb = MyNotebook(self, names)
        nb.pack()

        def add_label(parent, text, row, column):
            label = ttk.Label(parent, text=text)
            label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky=tk.N, pady=10)
            return label

        def payroll():
            nb.pr = dataframes.runpayroll(nb.name)

        def getname():
            nb.name = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file",
                                              filetypes=(("excel files", 
"*.xls"), ("all files", "*.*")))

        tab = nb.tabs['Payroll']
        add_label(tab, 'Click this button to process payroll', 1, 8)
        b1 = ttk.Button(tab, text="Run Payroll", command= payroll())
        b1.grid(row=2, column=8)
        b2 = ttk.Button(tab, text="Select SAR file", command=lambda: 
getname())
        b2.grid(row=3, column=8)

        return nb

    def create_menus(self):
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        sub_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=sub_menu)
        sub_menu.add_separator()
        sub_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.destroy)
        return menu


class MyNotebook(ttk.Notebook):

    def __init__(self, master, names):
        super().__init__(master, width=795, height=475)

        # Create tabs & save them by name in a dictionary
        self.tabs = {}
        for name in names:
            self.tabs[name] = tab = ttk.Frame(self)
            self.add(tab, text=name)


GUI()
```

But I guess this error: `AttributeError: 'MyNotebook' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: If you want `runpayroll` to be able to access `name`, you have to pass it as an argument. But the bigger problem is that you don't seem to have a `name` to pass it in the first place. The only thing  you have called `name` anywhere is a local variable in that `getname()` function, which isn't usable outside that function. All you do with it is `return name`, but the caller isn't doing anything with the return value, because it's just a Tkinter command callback.

Comment: Where would I put the line `name = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file",
                                          filetypes=(("excel` to be able to pass name as an argument into the `runpayroll` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `runpayroll` to be able to access `name`, you have to pass it as an argument.

But the bigger problem is that you don't seem to have a `name` to pass it in the first place.

The only thing  you have called `name` anywhere is a local variable in that `getname()` function, which isn't usable outside that function. All you do with it is `return name`, but the caller isn't doing anything with the return value, because it's just a Tkinter command callback.

You need to think about where you want to store these things. The usual answer is to create a class—either a subclass of `Notebook`, or a "controller" class that owns a `Notebook`—and store things as instance variables. As an inferior alternative, you can sometimes get away with storing things as global (or nonlocal) variables. But, however you decide to do it, someone has to assign the value to that instance or global variable somewhere. And then, you can pass it to `run_payroll`.

In this case, you seem to already have a `MyNotebook` class, and you're creating an instance of that, so maybe that's the right place to store things.

While we're at it, there's no reason to `return` anything from a function whose caller is just going to ignore the results. And also, you don't need `lambda: payroll()`; you can just use `payroll` for the same effect, but more readably (and even more efficiently).

So:

```
def create_notebook(self, names):
    nb = MyNotebook(self, names)
    nb.pack()
    # …

    def payroll():
        nb.pr = dataframes.runpayroll(nb.name)

    def getname():
        nb.name = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file",
                                             filetypes=(("excel 
files", "*.xls"), ("all files", "*.*")))    
    # …
```

And now, just change `runpayroll` to use that value:

```
def runpayroll(name):
    df_sar = pd.read_excel(name,
                           sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=4)
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying a little bit but two questions: 1.) What should I search on youTube for more info on this? and, 2.) Why does it give me `AttributeError: 'MyNotebook' object has no attribute 'name'`? pointing towards `def payroll():
            nb.pr = dataframes.runpayroll(nb.name)`

PS Thanks very much for your help! :)

Comment: @6seven8 (1) I have no idea; honestly, most of the YouTube videos I've seen have more misinformation than useful knowledge, so either most of them suck, or I'm the wrong person to ask. (2) If you don't call `getname` before calling `payroll`, there will be no name, right? How could it be otherwise? You could make the error message nicer by, e.g., setting `nb.name = None` and adding `if nb.name is None: <pop up some nice error message>`, or even disabling the payroll button until `nb.name` gets set.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you for the help! I fixed it.. How I did it was just to remove `def getname()` and make `def payroll():` look like this:
           def payroll():
                nb.name = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select 
    file",
                                                  filetypes=(("excel files", "*.xls"), 
    ("all files", "*.*")))
                nb.pr = dataframes.runpayroll(nb.name)